# Comparing two date in php

Tags: php

I need to compare two dates

```
d1= 12-11-01(YY-MM-DD) and d2=2008-05-02(YYYY-MM-DD)
```

comparison `d2 <= d1`

It is not working as per requirement

Here please note that I need to compare dates with different date formats.

Comment: change it to timestamp and then compare

Comment: convert it to unix time

Comment: What is 12? what is 11? What is 01? Year, month, day? Month, day, year? Day, month, year?... No answer considers this.

Comment: Can you reopen question Rikesh, tereško, dragon112, ircmaxell, Alexander as it is unique one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
$d1 = strtotime('12-11-01');
$d2 = strtotime('2008-05-02');

if ( $d2 <= $d1 ) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

[DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) is better than `strtotime()` because it can account for timezones and daylight savings time

```
$dt1 = new DateTime('12-11-01');
$dt2 = new DateTime('2008-05-02');
if ( $dt2 <= $dt1 ) {

}
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/8849f)

Answer (score 1):

Do this :

```
if(strtotime('12-11-01') <= strtotime('2008-05-02'))
{
     // do your task here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$d1 = strtotime($date1);
$d2 = strtotime($date2);
if($d2 <= $d1){
    // $date2 is before $date1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(strtotime('12-11-01') <= strtotime('2008-05-02'))
{   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like below,

```
if(strtotime($date1) < strtotime($date2)) {
    // do something
}
```

Research it further here

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php